# Omitting indices when condition isn't met

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing

I want to run a loop and when two things are not equal then I want that index to be omitted from my new structure. It works until it gets to the first inequality.Then it just stops looping for some reason and it doesn't pick up on j=46 after omitting j=45. I have no idea why. Here is the code

```
for j=1:length(files_cdf)
   z(j)=isequal(files_cdf(j).ith,list(j));
   if isequal(z(j),1)
      cdf_new(j)=files_cdf(j);
   else
      cdf_new(j)=[];
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches. The first one could incur a performance hit because it means you can't preallocate the `cdf_new` array.

```
for j=1:length(files_cdf)
   z(j)=isequal(files_cdf(j).ith,list(j));
   if isequal(z(j),1)
      cdf_new(end+1)=files_cdf(j);
   end
end
```

This just grows the array `cdf_new` for each element that you want to keep.

Alternatively, you can keep a separate counter for the index into `cdf_new`.

```
c=0;
for j=1:length(files_cdf)
   z(j)=isequal(files_cdf(j).ith,list(j));
   if isequal(z(j),1)
      c=c+1;
      cdf_new(c)=files_cdf(j);
   end
end
```

Using this technique, if you've preallocated your array `cdf_new`, you can just truncate it to only the valid values:

```
cdf_new = cdfnew(1:c);
```